# Unable to figure out NameError on local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers

My application_helper.rb file has the following code

```
module ApplicationHelper
def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
end
```

and I have a posts controller which has a method

```
def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.posted_by_uid=current_user.id
@post.posted_by=current_user.first_name+" "+current_user.last_name
@post.ups=0
@post.downs=0
@post.save
respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
        format.html {redirect_to root_path}
        format.json {render :json => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post}
    else
        format.html {redirect_to root_path}
        format.json {render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
end
```

However when I try to submit a form by the following view

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<div class="fields">
<%= f.label "Post" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :post %>
</div>
<div class="actions" id="refreshposts">
<%= f.submit("Post") %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

it returns an error undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Any help is appreciated

Comment: On which line does that error came?

Comment: @Pavan in app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:36:in `create' which is @post.posted_by_uid=current_user.id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include `ApplicationHelper` module in `ApplicationController` class so that `current_user` method would be available in the controllers.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper ## Add this line
  ## ...
end
```

Comment: Wow you are getting so much reputation, so quickly! congratulations ;)

Comment: You are back again! Good to see :)

Comment: @Krishna Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer when timeout is over :D

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thank You! And we should start the scoring again :)

Comment: @Pavan I was under the weather. But I am back now. And you got competition again. :D

Comment: Yes!You are very big for me to compete.But surely i will give a try :)

Comment: @KirtiThorat Ahah hmm no when I see your progression, I can not dare to compete with you! When we started you were 6 or 7k rep, not 15.2K !!